# copying parentNode of Node object

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm developing addon for firefox 24.0 with addon-sdk-1.14 and I've noticed some odd behavior when copying parentNode of a Node object.

Full content script file:

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");                             
if (imgs.length > 0) {                                                      
    var node = imgs.item(0);                                                
    var parent = node.parentNode.cloneNode();                               
    if (parent && node.parentNode) {                                        
        console.log(node.parentNode.nodeType);                              
        console.log(parent.nodeType);                                       
    }                                                                       
}
```

Output:

```
1
null
```

I am not familiar with javascript and I want to understand what's going on? Are we not allowed to make copies of Node objects, or what?

Comment: Please provide a full example (and/or http://builder.addons.mozilla.org link), so we can reproduce what you're seeing.

Comment: @nmaier I haven't published it yet, so I can't give you a link. Do you need just a content script or the whole directory hierarcy to reproduce it?

Comment: I posted the whole content script file. Do you need something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either change the name of the `parent` variable to something less obtrusive or put your code inside a self executing anonymous function (I suggest the former).

Comment: Ha, I changed name for `parent` variable and it worked. Why is that?

Comment: Because the stuff runs in a content script, and there is a built-in [window.parent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.parent) already. ;)

Comment: Actually, `Worker` hides `window.parent` behind a getter. And without a setter `parent` is effectively read only.

Answer (score 0):

Try `node.parentNode.nodeName`, you may be referencing a `textNode` or something else that can't be worked with by accident.

You can also cycle through available methods and properties the following way...

```
for (i in node.parentNode) {alert('i = '+i);}
```

Comment and I'll follow you along with this until you get to where you need to be.

Keep in mind that if you have `id` attributes they may be duplicated...

> Warning: cloneNode() may lead to duplicate element IDs in a document

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode#Notes

...and when you use JavaScript to refer to an `id` it will lead to unpredictable behavior.

Comment: `console.dir(node.parentNode)` should show all properties. Use `filter()` and `typeof prop == "function"` if you want methods/non-methods only.

Comment: You see, I don't get why results differ when I copy parentNode and when I don't. As for the properties of the object there are lost of them. The first few are: window, top, parent, unsafeWindow, console, imgs, i, node, newNode.

Comment: Do *any* of the elements you are cloning have an `id` attribute?

Comment: I find my object by document.getElementsByTagName("img"), so there should be no problems with id. Why should I pay attention whan cloneNode() does, is it invokes when I copy elements?

Comment: No, I am copying img with src and class attributes.

Comment: Have you tried to `appendChild` or `insertBefore` the image element someplace yet?

Comment: No, the only thing I do is printing nodeType.

Comment: Try to log one item, if it works try logging the second. Whichever one fails try to log the `typeof` and then that object (e.g. `console.log(typeof name)`.

Comment: Also are you using `cloneNode` to make copies because I don't see it in the code you've posted. If you use `appendChild` or insertBefore` for example they will simply move the element instead of clone it.

Comment: Both `typeof node.parentNode` and `typeof parent` yield object.

Comment: I don't use `cloneNode`, but when I do, eg. `var parent = node.parentNode.cloneNode()` the result is the same. I also do not mess with DOM. The only thing I do is print `nodeType`

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken there is no other way to "copy" an element other than `cloneNode`. For someone who claims to not know JavaScript too well you're fairly more advanced than you seem to think. You're using the console for testing purposes though I recommend you try using `cloneNode` beyond just the testing to see if it actually works. Beyond that the question has become a bit ambiguous to me. The only other thing that seems a bit odd is the mention of JSON in the error message.

Comment: What does assignment operator `=` do, if not copy object? Copy references (if there is such a thing in javascript)? But why the objects `parent` and `node.parentNode` are completely different then? As I mentioned above, I tried to use `cloneNode` but it yields the same results. Also, this is the content-script for  firefox-addon, maybe that's the reason of mystic behavior.

Comment: The `=` operator will *reference* the object, it won't actually copy it. Let's say `var i = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];` then you can change it's class by `i.className = 'different';`

Also I think when you are using the `in` operator make an exception for the `onEvent` object and see if it gets past that point.

Yes, I agree it is odd that `parent` and `node.parentNode` return differently, they shouldn't from my experience.

Comment: Hey, is there operator overloading in javascript? Maybe there is another script that redefines the meaning of assignment `=` for this type of object? However it's not likely. I tested it on several sites and all yiels the same results.

Comment: Change `if (node)` to ` if (node && name!='onEvent')`. Looking it up on Wiki JavaScript appears to support limited set but not New definable (whatever that is, I'm not familiar with that).